# Criar arquivo excel com c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou com um problema: tenho que gerar um classe no C# para criar um arquivo Excel, porém não estou conseguindo.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

A ideia é gerar um arquivo em Excel com um menu e uma linha com valores.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no NPOI: https://npoi.codeplex.com/

Comment: Criar a classe para gerar o Excel? Gerar o Excel com os dados de uma classe? O que seria, exatamente?

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm

Comment: Boa tarde amigo, a ideia e gerar um arquivo em excel com um menu e uma linha com valores .

Comment: Creio que isto ira te ajudar, o arquivo do excel sera criado a partir de um *dataTable*, de um olhada no [Link](http://www.macoratti.net/10/05/c_dtxls.htm)

Comment: Eu não entendi a parte do menu. O que ele teria. E os valores? De onde vêm? É uma linha só ou são várias? Edite sua pergunta e coloque mais detalhes, por favor.

Comment: Se for algo simples, só com números, existem várias formas de fazer isso programaticamente, manipulando elementos. Mas se for algo mais complexo, com formatação, e se você já conhece a ferramenta de report do visual studio (o Crystal também deve permitir isso, não conheço), uma boa opção é criar um report e exportar para xls. Se precisar fazer manutenção será bem mais fácil. Aqui tem um bom tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/888937/RDLC-Export-Directly-to-Word-Excel-or-PDF-from-Cod

Comment: Leo longhi. o que eu me referia a menu e valores seria a mesma coisa que: nome da coluna, exemplo: "NOME"
informação da coluna na linha de baixo, exemplo: "Joao"

Comment: Vou responder sua pergunta. [Acho legal você dar uma olhada nisso aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), pra conseguir aproveitar ao máximo o site.

Answer (score 6):

A melhor ferramenta que conheço para fazer o que você precisa é o [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus). [Há várias respostas minhas no site a respeito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+epplus).

Vou fazer um pequeno tutorial pra você sobre como usar.

## O mínimo do mínimo

```
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Jaderson Pessoa";
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Meu Excel";

    // Aqui você coloca a lógica que precisa escrever nas planilhas.

    string path = @"C:\teste.xlsx";
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

## Adicionando uma planilha e escrevendo nela

```
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Jaderson Pessoa";
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Meu Excel";

    // Aqui simplesmente adiciono a planilha inicial
    var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Planilha 1");
    sheet.Name = "Planilha 1";

    // Títulos
    var i = 1;
    var titulos = new String[] { "Título Um", "Título Dois", "Título Três" };
    foreach (var titulo in titulos)
    {
        sheet.Cells[1, i++].Value = titulo;
    }

    // Valores
    i = 1;
    var valores = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
    foreach (var valor in valores)
    {
        // Aqui escrevo a segunda linha do arquivo com alguns valores.
        sheet.Cells[2, i++].Value = valor;
    }

    string path = @"C:\teste.xlsx";
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

Acho que isso é um bom começo para sua classe C#.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que para ter um controle nesse nível de um excel sem precisar comprar uma lib de terceiro você pode usar a **Interop** do framework .net mesmo.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/dd264733.aspx

E aqui tem um guia completo de como criar planilhas excel usando a Interop

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx

Tente seguir o conteúdo desses links e complemente sua pergunta com dúvidas da implementação em si, assim tanto eu posso ir complementando a resposta afim de te ajudar como outras pessoas também poderão te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Colega, essa resposta está com baixíssima qualidade porque essencialmente ela só contém os links. Você poderia ter feito a sugestão dos links por comentário. Para melhorar a resposta, sugiro editá-la e adicionar um exemplo de código, ou melhor ainda, um resumo do que está descrito no link.

Comment: @LuizVieira Concordo com você que respostas com somente links normalmente são consideradas ruins. Porém para essa pergunta eu acho apropriado pois existem vários tutoriais na internet de como fazer isso e não acho que há valor em reproduzí-los aqui. Talvez o problema seja a própria pergunta.

Comment: @AlexDev A pergunta certamente tem problemas. Eu votei para fechá-la como não clara por que o autor diz "não estou conseguindo", mas não explica qual é a dificuldade (se é um erro de compilação, se não gera o resultado esperado, etc). Isso **não valida a resposta**, que como você mesmo concorda tem seus próprios problemas. O conteúdo da resposta não é ruim ou inútil, e eu concordo contigo: é apropriado... mas para um comentário. :)

Comment: @AlexDev Ah, e sobre "não haver valor em reproduzir (conteúdos) aqui", isso é bastante discutível. Qualquer conteúdo existe por aí afora, de forma que essa mesma linha de raciocínio levaria a acreditar que também não há valor em *perguntar* por aqui. Se o(a) AP veio aqui perguntar é porque ele(a) tem dificuldades, e a ideia deste site é construir colaborativamente uma base de conhecimento. Links *adicionais* são bem vindos, mas [respostas somente com links são altamente indesejadas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links).

Comment: @LuizVieira a minha intenção era que a pessoa que fez a pergunta seguisse os links para começar a tentar fazer o que ela queria e somente ai ela teria dúvidas reais (colocando a mão na massa) que ela pudesse postar aqui e então iria complementando a resposta de acordo com as dúvidas que fossem surgindo. Porém como escrevi na pressa aqui concordo que ficou vaga a resposta.

Comment: É uma ótima e nobre intenção, Erick. Mas não tem problema algum fazê-la em comentários. Vc, aliás, tem reputação suficiente para comentar em todas as publicações. O comentário serve esse mesmo propósito, e vc evita o risco de levar negativações (Não fui eu quem negativou, ok? Mas infelizmente isso ocorre com muita frequência em casos em que uma conversa como essa resolveria).

Comment: É que para essa pergunta o essencial da resposta é somente o nome da biblioteca ou técnica. Isso já é suficiente para o OP pesquisar como fazer isso. O link é só para economizar tempo. Mas como o Luiz disse, talvez o melhor lugar para isso seja em um comentário.

Comment: Compreendo o ponto de todos, embora não ache que a resposta deva ser negativada sendo que ela não está errada, apenas não é a melhor resposta que poderia ser. Em todo caso, compreendo a opinião de todos. Vou manter a resposta aqui para manter o histórico dos comentários que eu acho que é uma discussão muito útil e válida.